# Can't set widget url for Google Identity Toolkit

Tags: php, google-widget

I'm trying to set up a project with the google identity tollkit. I followed the steps of the [PHP quick-start guide](https://developers.google.com/identity-toolkit/quickstart/php) so far, but at step 9 I can't set a widget URL form my app. It just displays an empty drop-down menu and if I try to leave it empty it says "Required fields with an asterisk (*) should not be empty!"

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

- From the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity-toolkit/quickstart/php):

> If there are no selections in the drop-down menu, try selecting a different client ID on the other drop-down menu under Google on the right.
>
> One also needs to verify that the client id selected is the "Client ID for web application".